# jQuery .one - how do I to bind correctly

Tags: jquery

I have a HTML form that I want to start `submit_change` onclick. I was using `onclick="submit_change()"` but I want it to launch only once.

I have tried to use `.one` like this but one I click on `#submit_btn` my function `submit_change` is not starting

```
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit_btn").one('click', submit_change);
});

function submit_change() {
//do stuff
}
```

Comment: What's "not working" about it?  In what way does it fail?  Your code seems to demonstrably work just fine: https://jsfiddle.net/noL75ztx/

Comment: @David I have edited my question to clarify - thanks

Comment: Can you provide additional debugging information?  Is there any error on the browser's development console?  When the handler is bound, is `submit_change` indeed this defined function?  Does the selector find the target element at that time?  When the element is clicked, is there any error on the console?  If you empty the `submit_change` function and add a single line of code and place a breakpoint, is that breakpoint reached?  The code shown demonstrably works, so we need to narrow down the problem.

Answer (score 0):

It's working

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#submit_btn").one('click', submit_change);
});

function submit_change() {
console.log("Clicked once!")
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button id="submit_btn">Click me</button>
```